# Python RSA - Public Key Encryption Gives Error?

Tags: python, json, encryption, rsa

I am trying to encrypt the JSON data with RSA public key and decrypt using private key,
My code,

```
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
import binascii

final_data = { 'custom_folder': {'check': 'test'} }

data = json.dumps(final_data).encode('utf-8') # converted into bytes

keys = RSA.generate(2048)
pub_key = keys.publickey().exportKey('PEM') # generates public key
pri_key = keys.exportKey('PEM') # generate private key

encryptor = PKCS1_OAEP.new(key=keys) # using keys variable
encrypted = encryptor.encrypt(data)
print("Encrypted:", binascii.hexlify(encrypted))
```

When done using variable `keys` it encrypts the data like this,

```
Encrypted: b'46bdca64f486....'
```

But i want to use my public key to encrypt and send the data and at he other end decrypt using just the private key, when i replace the `keys` with the `pub_key` generates this error

```
encryptor = PKCS1_OAEP.new(key=pub_key) # replaced keys with public key

# Error geenrated
Traceback (most recent call last):
  encrypted = encryptor.encrypt(data)
  modBits = Crypto.Util.number.size(self._key.n)
AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'n'
```

How do i encrypt using a public key only?

Comment: You must apply in `PKCS1_OAEP.new()` either `keys.publickey()` or `RSA.importKey(pub_key)`, where `pub_key` is a PEM encoded public key, as in your example.

Comment: Seconded. An RSA public key consists of modulus and exponent. What you are giving the API is the *encoding* of the public key, not the public key object itself.

Comment: Got it, i knew when i opened the new function the param did say key object but couldn't find how to convert that into the object.